# gradle making war with overwriting resource

Tags: gradle, resources, duplicates, war, overwrite

```
if( project.target == 'custom') {
            war {
                from( "custom/overwrite/icons", {
                    into '/'
                })
```

It's my part of gradle code. I tried to overwrite icon through above code.
But When I see inside war, both origin icon and new icon are exist.
weird thing is they are same file name. how should I replace or overwrite icon?

I tried 'DuplicatesStrategy' API. When it is set as 'exclude', no icon is included in war.
when it is set as 'include', both icons are included in war. Any idea of this?